# Facebook Safari OSX Youtube wmode bug

Tags: facebook, safari, youtube, wmode

I'm having an issue that is specific to Safari on Mac OSX, where setting wmode to transparent is not preventing facebook modal windows, or drop downs from being overlapped by the video.  We have tried opaque, transparent, and a handful of other hacks from around the net, but can not seem to resolve the issue in Safari.  Can anyone help resolve the issue, or reproduce it?

```
iframe title="YouTube video player" width="520" height="290" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TP790i87rBc?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0">
```

Thanks!

Bob

Answer (score -2):

I recently had the same problem. It looks like YouTube has also changed its embed code from `<object>` to `<iframe>`, yet neither of these worked for me. The solution for my project was to just use the `<embed>` tag.

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="' + videoSource + '" width="640" height="390" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" bgcolor="#000000"></embed>
```